# Background transparent image is making text ugly and hard to read - CSS

Tags: html, css

Using background cover image with some transparency making my top navigation menu links text ugly and harder to read. How can I make it correct?

HTML -

```
    <div id="wrapper"> <!-- wrapper starts here -->
    <div id="header"> <!-- header starts here -->
        <h1>example.com</h1>
    </div> <!-- header ends here -->
    <div id="top_nav"> <!-- nav starts here -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
   <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>  <!-- nav ends here -->
    <div style="height:1000px;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
html
{ 
    background:url(http://www.designmyprofile.com/images/graphics/backgrounds/background0172.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
}

#wrapper
{
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

#top_nav
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#3079ED;
    position:relative;
}

#top_nav ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#top_nav ul li
{
    float:left;
}

#top_nav ul li a
{
    background-color:#3079ED;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:8px 16px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:14px;
    border-right:1px solid #6199DF;
}

#top_nav ul li:last-child a
{
    border-right:none;
}

#top_nav ul li a:hover
{
    background-color:#6199DF;
}
```

So please tell me how can I make my menu link text clean and more readable as regular text while keeping the background image transparency.

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/06yagehc/11/)

Comment: sorry, am I missing something? I can easily read the text in the demo provided...I don't get what you're after

Answer (score 0):

Read back again and see your main problems are how you chose to do the background, and that the bar doesn't extend across as the CSS says it should. Try to make these modifications.

In #topnav {}

Below

```
width: 100%;
```

add

```
height: 32px;
```

The height being 0px is causing the short menu bar error. Also you can remove

```
position:relative;
```

It is assumed in this case already.

I would also change the background of wrapper from

```
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
```

to

```
background-color:rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.45);
```

and add

```
h1
{
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
}
```

This tends to do better on backgrounds comprised at least half of darker tones.

Should fix your short nav bar problem and make everything easier to read. As well as show off your background better.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5e5e8Lej/13/)

Comment: change the **font-family** also .then u can get good readability for user